# Google Play services out of date. Requires 4030500 but found 3266132

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just made an update and I can't execute my project any more.
It says:

```
10-31 23:23:18.033: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(28737): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3266132

10-31 23:23:18.143: E/AndroidRuntime(28737): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xoco.checker/com.xoco.checker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
```

It was just working fine 30 minutes ago, so I may think the update causes it.

I have read about similar issue, but always with an emulator and I'm testing with a Samsung Galaxy Fame.

I haven't been able to find any problem in my code. Can you please help me?

**EDIT:**
Where can I find the updated apk (Google Play Services, revision 13) (gms and vending)

Comment: You update the Play Services through, ADT Manager, but Play service on device are still old, Update play services, or best suggestion use Genymotion as testing device.

Comment: FYI, check my answeron the other same question.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19760215/536078

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install play service for Froyo may help

[image]

Comment: just remember that this answer is a workaround since the real solution will be to have Google Play Services updated in your device. However, it looks like Google hasn't updated it in the Google Play (at least not in all the servers)

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem was yesterday. I solution it with help Google Play Service for Froyo(Rev. 12). With Rev. 13 not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a device with a really old copy of Google Play Services. Updating it on the device fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem, the solution for me is return the .jar (google play service for Froyo), excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: What do you mean by “return the .jar”?

Comment: How can you return the jar?  You use gradle to import your dependencies.