# Google services added Force close application with log cat error

Tags: android

I have been developing a simple app for load a map view. I have followed the API.     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map

BUT

after the execution app goes force close and a LOGCAT ERROR 
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 4030500 but found 0.
 this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.newgmaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA5QozHkGwJP_9iJi7jtBV938T1wws02gA" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.newgmaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

this is my main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and this is main activity

```
package com.example.newgmaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the stacktrace!

Comment: Check this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724113/google-play-services-update?noredirect=1#comment29303121_19724113

Comment: I have used this block
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 and it says in the app have to update Google play services... Don't know what is it and how to do it.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas I have tried it but not working

Comment: Did you add "<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />" in your <application> tag ??

Comment: yes i have then a dialog box apppeard in the app and say you need to update the google play service...etc when click on it it automatically directs to google play services.. but i dont know how to update it

Comment: @SiddharthVyas can you please help me with this... :(

Comment: to Update your "Google play Service" go to SDK manager ->Extras-> Google play service update that it will update to current revision requirment

Comment: Actually at SDK manager there I have updated version.

Comment: are you trying to run on emulator..?

Comment: You need to install google play services as a library:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724547/google-services-added-force-close-application-with-log-cat-error/19775476?s=633a6480-ed14-46f1-9cb0-1ae6bf5c715d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do these 2 steps and let me know please

1st update your Google play services as show here
[image]

2nd try out this new manifest file that i have created for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newgmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.newgmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="icom.example.newgmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA5QozHkGwJP_9iJi7jtBV938T1wws02gA" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newgmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

let me know if you solved this problem also
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the previous version of Google Play Services libproject for now. It can be downloaded from here: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_3225130_r10.zip

Worked for me.

You can then update this later when Google makes the latest version available to everyone but something tells me it will be a while before this change propagates to all the devices out there.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when running the app on my 2012 N7 running 4.3.

I don't think the actual released version of Play Services matches the SDK version in `version.xml`:

```
google_play_services_version 4030500
```

So it's either a case of waiting for a Play Services update on Play Store, or possibly try changing the `version.xml` in `google-play-services_lib.`

Comment: Forget to say - this was after adding the metadata line to the manifest.

Comment: Just tried editing the version.xml and it didn't work - it requires 4030500, so it's a case of waiting for Play Store update or reverting to the previous services_lib version.

Comment: yeah of course same problem here. I guess have to wait.. anyway keep in touch.. thank you

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the update of Google Play Services in the Play Store, grab the APK of Play Services 4.0 from one of the latest dumps: http://www.droid-life.com/2013/10/31/download-new-google-apps-from-the-nexus-5-dump-search-launcher-and-more/ (first download)

Answer (score 1):

If you start the Android SDK manager you should see a "Google play services for Froyo" module. Install  and use this instead of the "new" version. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Google must update Google play services to version 4.xxx
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added this below xml code in "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<Application 
...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...
</Application>
```

The crash error was disappeared. 
But when I call...

```
int iErrorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

"iErrorCode" is 2. 2 means like this

> **public static final int SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED** 
>   The installed version of Google Play services is out of date. The calling activity should pass this error code to getErrorDialog(int, Activity, int) to get a localized error dialog that will resolve the error when shown.
>   Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
>   [Details...](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED)

And also LogCat said...

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4728): Google Play services out of date. **Requires 4030500 but found 3266136**

Where is version code "4030500"??

> [SDK]\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values

You can see "version.xml". Open it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>
</resources>
```

Peekaboo~~! :)
This is why we got this errorCode(2) when update new SDK and use new "google-play-services-lib".

Okay! Got it! Let's check my Google Play Version on my device.

[image]

The version on my phone is "4.4.21" There is no problem I think.
What is this "3266136"? Where were this from? I cannot understand this.

If I figure this out, I will update this long answer.

Good luck! Everybody! :)

**Updated 1:**
I downloaded apk 4.4.22 and installed on my phone. But, LogCat still show me "3266136".
This is really odd thing. I think Google-Team have to fix it ASAP!!

[4.4.22 Download here...](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/01/download-latest-google-play-store-4-4-22/)

**Updated 2:**
After all, I decided to down-grade "google-play-services_lib" and "android-support-v4.jar" to previous version. I will be wait for them. :)

Comment: @ShootSahan Google updated their "play service lib" last week. So, this problem was solved. I tested lib and works well. See this : http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html

Answer (score 0):

try to add this meta-data tag in the application tag in the Manifest :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: that gives me an error at the manifest: Cannot resolve symbol '@integer/google_play_services_version'

Comment: I added that to the manifest. No errors but it is asking to update play services over and over again...

Comment: execute in a real device

Comment: @LucasJota Try this ugly and bad workaround: 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />