# Google Plus Android API : "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plus, google-play-services

I am playing with the Google sample app relative to the Google Plus SDK (sample app provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)

I can run the sample app. But when I want to login to Google Plus from within the app, I get the message: "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services". If I click on the update button, I see that I have got the last update of the Google Play Services (v3.2.66). In Eclipse, I have got rev. 13 of Google Plus SDK.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you testing your app on the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: On device (Samsung S4).

Comment: U can solve this problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721415/mayday-google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-4030500-but-found-3266132

Comment: Thanks ! Now it works when I click on +1 and then on the OK button in the Google+ window which appears. But if I click on the "share" button, the Google+ app crashes in background and I get " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.plus/com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.ShareActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity started without an EXTRA_ACCOUNT" How can I solve this issue ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Google+ app that is fixed in the latest build that came out today: https://plus.google.com/101870761930221849874/posts/KohXe9pBGF6 Sorry about that.