# Google Admob ads not showing Android

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am using https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play, to add admob ads to my android application but I am unable to do so. I followed the link on stackoverflow 
[Google Play services out of date. Requires 4030500 but found 3266132](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721415/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-4030500-but-found-3266132)
but it could not solve my issue.

I am getting the warning :-W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5051): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4448036

and error:-E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(8963): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2

I have updated my Google Play Services jar also

Answer (score 2):

The error says `Google Play services out of date. Requires 4452000 but found 4448036` - that means your device needs to install the newest version of Google Play Services. Per [ensuring Google Play Services exists](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure), you can use [GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#getErrorDialog%28int,%20android.app.Activity,%20int%29), passing in the error code to generate the correct dialog to allow the user to correct any problems.

Comment: does that mean all those devices which do not have updated Google Play Services will not be able to see the ads if they install my application?

Comment: Not until they are auto-updated to the latest version of Google Play Services, which happens automatically in the background. You're actually probably fairly lucky to run into this particular error on a real device :)

Comment: Also I should note that there is a less obtrusive way of notifying the user he should update his Google Play Services - via a Notification. `GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this), this);`